# persist a 1 column table using JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, jpql

I've got a table with only one column. It's an Id

How can I persist it with JPA?

I've tried a **entityManager.persist(new OneColumnTable());**

and it throws a PersistenceException

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6023] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: **The list of fields to insert into the table [DatabaseTable(OneColumnTable)] is empty.  You must define at least one mapping for this table.**
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:418)
```

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OneColumnTable")
public class OneColumnTable implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OneColumn")
    private Integer oneColumn;

    public OneColumnTable() {

    }

    public Integer getOneColumn() {
        return oneColumn;
    }

    public void setOneColumn(Integer oneColumn) {
        this.oneColumn= oneColumn;
    }

}
```

**TABLE**

```
USE [myDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OneColumnTable]    Script Date: 07/15/2011 12:10:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OneColumnTable](
    [OneColumn] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OneColumn] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: It seems strange that you'd want to do this. I haven't come a across an RDBMS that would understand `insert into OneColumnTable() values();`. Perhaps there's a design problem here.

Comment: design problem for sure, but they want me to do it like this, so i'd like to know if it's possible :(

Comment: Many RDBMS support such a statement ... but see my answer below there are different sintaxis

Answer (score 1):

DataNucleus can persist that class fine. The thing is for some RDBMS the INSERT statement has to be of a particular type when no columns are being specified (since your only column is being generated in the datastore), and this is presumably what it can't do. In the case of SQLServer the statement that any decent JPA implementation ought to generate is "INSERT INTO {tbl} DEFAULT VALUES". Perhaps get an implementation that does that?

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` indicates the use of a sequencing strategy that is dependent on the [database support for `IDENTITY` columns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Identity_sequencing).

The concept of `IDENTITY` columns is not present in all databases. For instance, Apache Derby and Oracle do not support this, while MySQL, MSSQL (and typically, Sybase), supports the IDENTITY sequencing strategy. You should be using a sequencing strategy that is supported by your database. For portability, choose the `AUTO` or `TABLE` sequencing strategies. In most JPA providers, the `AUTO` strategy is implemented as the `TABLE` sequencing strategy, as all databases support the creation of a table for maintaining the sequence values.

Comment: Is there a larger stack trace? As far as I can see, there are no open bugs against EclipseLink as far as IDENTITY sequencing in concerned in MSSQL for this behavior, and I cannot see how this simple case could fail. Unfortunately, I do not have access to a MSSQL instance, so I'll need to look at the source of EclipseLink to help you here; and that's why I would be interested in a stacktrace that pinpoints the exact location of failure.

Comment: SQLServer definitely supports IDENTITY keywords and hence JPA "IDENTITY" value generation.

Comment: @DataNucleus, no one here is doubting whether MSSQL supports IDENTITY columns or not. This might be an edge case triggered in EclipseLink against the MSSQL platform. The support for IDENTITY sequencing relies on issuing a `SELECT @@IDENTITY` query as codified in the `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform` class. The query itself is issued only after firing an insert in the database. It is likely that the query-after-insert failed, but there is no way to know why it failed, or whether it was the initial point of failure.